# HTML is not rendering properly in nodemailer

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, nodemailer

```
<div style = "height:auto;width:auto; background-color:#5C81F4;display:flex; justify-content:center;">
    <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column; width:90vw;height:auto;overflow:hidden;border-radius:20px; background-color:#ffffff;margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:40px;">
    <h1 style="display:flex; justify-self:center; align-self:center;color:#2A2836;">Quote of the Day</h1>
    <p style = "font-size:30px;height:auto; color:#2A2836;margin-left:10px;overflow:hidden;">
      "${quote}"
    </p>
    <p style ="display:flex; margin-right:10px; font-size:20px;color:#2A2836;justify-self:end;align-self:end">- <i>${author}</i></p>
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

This is my html code which I want to send as mail to the receiver. But in the receiver all the element of html are shown in single horizontal line as shown in the picture.
[image]

But HTML is properly rendering in the codepen as shown in the figure
[image]

I don't think there is problem with my html code. I don't know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is still not fully supported by email clients.

Your content is not being stacked the way you expect because in:

```html
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;">
```

The `flex-direction:column` has poor support. See [here](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=flex-direction).

For best results you will need to adopt an approach that has wider support.

Answer (score 0):

As @JQueeny said `flex-direction:column` is not supported. It seems like you are using gmail, hence `justify-content` is [not supported](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css#supported_css) as well.

In your case you can use `margin:auto`, `text-align:center`, `float:right` as a workaround. ([Now gmail supports the use of <style>](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css#example), but try to stick with inline style for wider compatibility.)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
  .parent {
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
      background-color: #5C81F4;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .quote-container {
      /* display: flex; */
      /* flex-direction: column; */
      width: 90vw;
      height: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 20px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      /* margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;*/
      margin: 40px auto;
    }
    
    .quote-title {
      /* display: flex; */
      /* justify-self: center; */
      /* align-self: center; */
      color: #2A2836;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .quote-body {
      font-size: 30px;
      height: auto;
      color: #2A2836;
      margin-left: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .quote-author {
      display: flex;
      margin-right: 10px;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #2A2836;
      float: right;
      /* justify-self: end; */
      /* align-self: end */
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="quote-container">
      <h1 class="quote-title">Quote of the Day</h1>
      <p class="quote-body">
        "To be yourself in a world that is constanly trying to make you something eslse is the gretest accomplishment."
      </p>
      <p class="quote-author">-
        <i>Roshan Ojha</i>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```